# Text Color Not Changing in AlertDialogue

Tags: java, android

I am trying to apply custom color in AlertDialogue. Its changing text color as well background color in it but not changing SingleChoiceItems text color. You can see it black color in it with page number like below image.

[image]

I am using style like below code

```
<style name="AlertDialogTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.Dialog.Alert">
        <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
        <item name="android:textColor">@color/TextColorLite</item>
        <item name="android:background">@color/colorPrimaryDarkLite</item>
        <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
        <item name="colorAccent">?attr/MainAccentColor</item>
        <item name="android:buttonBarButtonStyle">@style/DialogButtonStyle</item>
    </style>
    <style name="DialogButtonStyle" parent="@style/Widget.AppCompat.Button.ButtonBar.AlertDialog">
        <item name="android:textColor">?attr/TextColor</item>
        <item name="android:textStyle">bold</item>

    </style>
```

Java Code For Dialoge

```
AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(
                    getActivity(), R.style.AlertDialogTheme);
            builder.setTitle("Go to Page:");
            builder.setSingleChoiceItems(mPageOptions, mPageIndx - 1,
                    new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog,
                                            int item) {
                            mOptionDiag.dismiss();
                            mPageIndx = item + 1;
                            updateQuotesListServer();
                            updatePageInfo();
                        }
                    });

            builder.setNegativeButton("Dismiss",
                    new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog,
                                            int id) {

                        }

                    });
            mOptionDiag = builder.create();
            mOptionDiag.show();
```

What I should do for change this black text color ?

Thanks

Comment: please add all the styles you are using in this style, it can be the issue in other styles

Comment: I am not using any other style for dialogue.

Answer (score 1):

I have got solved adding this items in style.

```
 <!--For List Text-->
<item name="textColorAlertDialogListItem">@color/TextColorLite</item>
<!--For Radio-->
<item name="android:textColorSecondary">@color/TextColorLite</item>
```

Thanks

Comment: Yes ! This must be the solution.!

Answer (score 0):

In your resources folder open styles.xml and add a custom theme like for example this:

```
<style name="radiobuttonstyle" parent="Material.Drawable.RadioButton">
    <!-- Hint color and label color in FALSE state -->
    <item name="android:textColorHint">@color/md_green_900</item>
    <item name="android:textSize">20sp</item>
    <!-- Label color in TRUE state and bar color FALSE and TRUE State -->
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/md_green_400</item>
    <item name="colorControlNormal">@color/md_green_900</item>
    <item name="colorControlActivated">@color/md_green_400</item>
</style>
```

and in your RadioButton in your layout add it as the theme of your RadioButton like this:

```
    <RadioButton
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/radioyes"
        android:theme="@style/radiobuttonstyle"
        android:text="Yes"
        android:textColorLink="@color/md_light_green_900"
        android:textColorHighlight="@color/md_green_900"
        android:textColor="@color/md_light_green_900" />
```

**PS:** that is my own custom radio button so it should work.

Comment: Hi ! Thanks for quick answer. Can you please check my edited question. I have added java code of dialogue. Its using singlechoice item. sorry for some mistake in posting. Thanks

Comment: I am not using radio button...where should I put radio button code ?

Comment: on your Layout.